# jQuery serialized multidimensional form data unable to read in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

I am sending multidimensional form data to php through ajax in jQuery, I am able read single parameters, but I am unable to read multidimensional form elements. I am getting those multi dimensional keys as single strings

Here I am adding my adding my HTML, JQUERY and PHP code

**PHP**

```
<?php $document_index=1;?>
<div class="document-block" id="document_<?php echo $selected_document; ?>">
        <a class="delete-btn" href="javascript:;" onclick="delete_document(this);"><i class="la la-close"></i></a>
        <input type="hidden" class="document_index" value="<?php echo $document_index; ?>"/>
        <?php
        if (!empty($qualification_id)) {
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" class="qualification_id"
                   name="qualifications[document][<?php echo $document_index; ?>][qualification_id]"
                   value="<?php echo $qualification_id; ?>"/>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php
                    echo $document_options[$selected_document];
                    ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="qualifications[document][<?php echo $document_index; ?>][document_type]"
                           value="<?php echo $selected_document; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="kt-radio-inline">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($qualification_opts as $current_option) {
                            ?><label class="kt-radio kt-radio--bold kt-radio--brand">
                            <input type="radio" name="qualifications[document][<?php echo $document_index; ?>][option]"
                                   value="<?php echo $current_option; ?>"
                                   <?php if (strcasecmp($selected_option, $current_option) == 0){ ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>/>
                            <?php echo $current_option; ?>
                            <span></span>
                            </label><?php
                        }
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var form_data = $(formEl).serializeArray();
    console.log(form_data);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: user_url + 'jobdata/preview/',
        data: {
            form_data: form_data
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (retval) {
            console.log(retval);
            $("#preview_container").html(retval);
        }
    });
```

**Response**

```
[email_receipts[]] => jobs@toours.com
    [qualifications[location][1][qualification_id]] => 1
    [qualifications[location][1][location]] => Hyderabad
    [qualifications[location][1][option]] => Preferred
    [qualifications[education][1][qualification_id]] => 8
    [qualifications[education][1][level]] => masters
    [qualifications[education][1][option]] => Preferred
    [qualifications[experience][1][qualification_id]] => 9
    [qualifications[experience][1][years]] => 1
    [qualifications[experience][1][type]] => 5
    [qualifications[experience][1][option]] => Preferred
    [qualifications[experience][2][qualification_id]] => 10
    [qualifications[experience][2][years]] => 1
    [qualifications[experience][2][type]] => 6
    [qualifications[experience][2][option]] => Preferred
    [qualifications[document][1][qualification_id]] => 12
    [qualifications[document][1][document_type]] => police_verification
    [qualifications[document][1][option]] => Preferred
```

Can any body suggest how to convert this? Please

Comment: Please add the code your using to generate the data.

Comment: Show your HTML. If it has things like `name="qualifications[location][1][qualification_id]"` then the value should be in `$_POST['qualifications']['location'][1]['qualification_id']`. But what you've shown looks like you didn't create the POST data correctly. You should use `$("#form").serialize()`.